# PyCord staff role that persists across restarts

Tags: discord, pycord

How can I make it so that someone with "Manage Server" permissions can run /staffrole  and make that an admin role? I know that most major bots have a setting to add moderator roles.

I tried using lists, but those don't persist across bot restarts.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: As in, how can I make a slash command that allows a user to add a role to the list of bot managers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would definitely check out PyCord permissions module found below.
https://docs.pycord.dev/en/master/_modules/discord/commands/permissions.html

Permissions can be tricky at times with PyCord. Persistence across restarts is done through either storing the user in some sort of database, or simply, just a .json file.

First, you should declare a new slash command. From there, you can add a field using PyCord's Option module to take a server member in as a parameter. Then, you can store that member's ID in persistent storage. Another easy way to tackle this issue would be to use permission numbers to check if the member trying to execute the command has the "Manage Server" permission.